# How do I modify a debian/ubuntu based gnu autotooling build to fedora 32?

Tags: fedora, automake, autotools

[Slurm](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm) is an open source project using gnu autotools to build.
The problem is as follows:
when applying autoreconf to the project, the Makefile.in files created are missing the runstatedir macro.

I'm using Fedora 32, and after filing a bug with the project owners (Schedmd) I've received a WONTFIX resolution with the [following answer](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9165#c2):

> This is due to differences between the Debian/Ubuntu vs. Fedora
>   autotools packaging.
>
> The build tooling is managed on Debian/Ubuntu - which does not produce
>   such a diff today. Thus I won't be applying this.

My question is - can I modify anything in the project to make it "universally" correct - that is - ensure autoreconf does the right thing on both Fedora and Ubuntu?

The Fedora autotools package used is current as of this writing:
rpm autoconf-2.69-33.fc32.noarch

I have no idea which autoconf version is used in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: I suggest looking at how Fedora packages slurm. Here is the spec file for f32: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/slurm/blob/f32/f/slurm.spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the latest stable autoconf version, 2.69, was released eight years ago, in 2012.

In 2013 a Red Hat employer added the --runstatedir option (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=commit;h=a197431414088a417b407b9b20583b2e8f7363bd). But since there has not been a stable release since then the option has never been released.

Debian adds the patch to its autoconf package (https://sources.debian.org/patches/autoconf/2.69-11.1/add-runstatedir.patch/), so you can see the option in the wild. But Fedora doesn't.

By the end of October this year, 2020, autoconf 2.70 is planned to be released (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2020-09/msg00006.html) which will solve the issue.

I don't expect Fedora 33 to include it, though. So until Fedora 34, next year, the issue will still be there for you.

Unless you have any hurry the solution is to just wait.